# Calculated cell's for Average calculation

Tags: excel, average

I have an Excel sheet where I would like to calculate an Moving average of 15 numbers, with a Moving average length as a variable in possision D1, so I can change the value i D1, and then less or more values are in the calculation of the moving average, is that possible ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried averageif()? Might do what you want but difficult to say without a clear example.

Comment: No Sorry, can't see that AVERAGEIF() can help me, and I am not quite sure how to explain it better. 
But I would like to have the opportunity to change the number of cells I want to calculate the average for, just by inserting a number into a cell, as a kind of variable. Does it make sense ?

Comment: A clear example might make sense.

Comment: Hi Mike - Does this make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(ROW()>( MA_Len),AVERAGE(INDEX($A:$A,ROW()+1-MA_Len):INDEX($A:$A,ROW())),"")
```

[image]